# KDBG watch all arg variables

Tags: c, argv, kdbg

I need to be able to add the `argv` array to the watched variable list in KDBG for a C program I am running. I can add `argv[0]`,`argv[1]`,`argv[2]` etc but is there a way to add one variable that will allow me to watch the entire array regardless of how many variables there are?

Answer (score 0):

Use GDB's `@` notation to print an array.
Specify this expression

```
*argv@argc
```

to see all arguments, or

```
*argv@(argc+1)
```

to also see the trailing `NULL` pointer.